# How to create a WordPress custom endpoint that requires a php file with functionality every-time it's refreshed

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, endpoint

I am quite new to WordPress and REST Api from WP.
I have wrote a code where I am importing the data from an external database to WooCommerce database. I have saved this code into a php file named dbImportFunction.php. This works perfectly on localhost and does what's supposed to do. However, I am trying to integrate this code into WordPress via a custom endpoint, for example company/import and have no idea how to make use of the code I already wrote.
Perhaps it's a dumb question but I would be very happy if somebody could point me in the right direction.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wooCommerceProducts_endpoint');

function wooCommerceProducts_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route('company', '/import', array(
//In the code I already wrote I am using GET, PUT and POST so I'm confused of the method I have to use below
        'methods' => 'POST', 
        'callback' => 'update_or_create',
    ));
}

function update_or_create() {
   //make use of the code I already wrote and maybe show a Success or Failed button accordingly if the import succeeded or failed
}
```

When I'm going on the wp-json/company/import I should automatically start the import process..

Comment: You are using the Rest API here, so what you are asking, makes rather little sense to begin with. An API like this is meant to be used in the background.

Comment: Sure I understand that, but what I am trying to achieve is that whenever somebody accesses that endpoint, it triggers the code I wrote in a separate php file, then show a success or failed tag. I'd even be happy if it shows nothing, I can work on that later, just to integrate the functionality of the other php file into this endpoint.

Comment: Well then put that code you have already written into the `update_or_create` function? I’m guessing that code is probably not currently using WP functionality for the database operations - so if you don’t want to rewrite it in that regard, you’ll have to include the part that creates a connection to the database as well.

Comment: It does have WP functionality, it gets the data from an external DB, posts it into WC if WC does not already have any data in the DB, otherwise checks if it has to update the existing products on the WC database and if not creates it. I pretty much have the functionality I want, but do not know how to create the connection between it and a custom endpoint

Comment: Well the first and second argument to register_rest_route make up the URL for this endpoint, so making a POST request to `yourdomain.xy/company/import/` is what you would need to do here to trigger this.

Comment: I am running it on localhost so when I go for example on http://localhost:8000/wp-json/company/import I should be able to trigger that process, which exists in a separate php file. My question is what am I supposed to do with that php file and where do i have to put it or register it in order to get triggered on that endpoint?

Comment: No, just calling that URL in your browser will not trigger it - because that would be a GET request, and you registered your route for POST. And as I already said, the callback function you specified is what will get executed when that route is hit, so put what you need to do inside of that … If you don’t want to put the full code in that place, then use include/require to have it read from a different file.